# Changing Web Page based on page landed on

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm interested in tracking calls and wanted to know if anyone could offer any advice in regards to how to change the phone number on a web page based on the page on the site an individual lands on.

So say for instance someone lands on example.com/page1

The page 1 phone number would now show on all pages in replace of the standard phone number.

if someone lands on example.com/page2 the phone number for page 2 will now show across the entire website.

How would one go about setting something like this up? Also as far as the site goes I'm currently running wordpress. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
-John

Comment: Do you use server or hosting for your website?